# Predicting class based on context and historical data

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to develop a keras Model that will predict the binary class of an event. As input, for every event I have the context of the event (a variable in the range 0 to 10) and historical data of the event of type `[range(0, 10), class]`.

The class is computed as this: if the event is "good", the expected output is 1 if the context is > 5, or 0 if that's not the case. If it's bad, then the expected class is 1 for context < 5 and 0 if that's not the case. Same thing for historical data, class is 1 if event is good and past_context > 5 and so on

My goal is that the model learn from the historical data if this is a historically "good" or "bad" event, and use this to predict the output based on the context (if model is historically "good" and context is > 5, output 1, and so on).

Example:

| Context | Historical Data | Expected Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | `[[5, 1], [3, 0], [7, 1]]` | 1 |
| 3 | `[[2, 1], [6, 0], [4, 1]]` | 1 |
| 8 | `[[1, 1], [7, 0], [9, 0]]` | 0 |

Here is my data generation function:

```
def __getitem__(self, _):
    'Generate one batch of data'
    races = []
    X = []
    y = []
    for _ in range(self.batch_size):
        _races = []
        good = choice([0, 1])
        _X = randrange(10)
        _y = int(_X >= 5 if good else _X < 5)
        # _y = good
        y.append(_y)
        X.append(_X)
        for __ in range(self.nb_races):
            new_race_g = randrange(10)
            _y = int(new_race_g >= 5 if good else new_race_g < 5)
            _races.append([new_race_g, _y])
        races.append(_races)
    # return np.array(races), np.array(y)
    return [np.array(X), np.array(races)], np.array(y)
```

Here is the model I use:

```
data = DataGenerator()

numeric_input = Input(shape=(1), name='numeric_input')
hist_sequences = Input(shape=(10, 2), name='hist_sequences')

emb = Dense(4)(hist_sequences)
emb = GlobalMaxPool1D()(emb)


num_input = Dense(4)(numeric_input)

end = Concatenate(axis=1)([emb, num_input])
end = Dense(4)(end)
end = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid", name="output_dense")(end)

model = Model(inputs=[numeric_input, hist_sequences], outputs=[end])
print(model.summary())
model.compile("adam", "binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit_generator(data, epochs=5)
```

By disabling the context part, I am able to correctly predict if this is a good or bad event, so I suspect what I'm doing wrong is the combination of historical and context data, but as it is just a simple concat, I can't find the problem. With the context part, I can't go higher than 50% accuracy, which means it's just a random guess...

Note: I know I could just predict from historical data and use a simple if condition to predict from the context, however my goal is to integrate this in a more complex model with different data, and this is just a testing part